# $t$ Channel for Quark-Antiquark Annihilation/Scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I am getting slightly confused with when to use $s$, $t$ and $u$ channel for scattering/annihilation at lowest order.

If we have the Feynman diagrams for a process $q \overline{q} \rightarrow ZZ$ do we need $t$ and $u$ channel because the two final state particles are indistinguishable, or do we need $t$ and $s$ channel because there are both particles and antiparticles?

Is that the fact that the two final particles are indistinguishable not relevant if we already know that we have a particle and an antiparticle going in?

Edit: I checked other documents in the literature and it seems that for $q \overline{q} \rightarrow gg$, you actually must consider all the channels ($s$, $t$ and $u$) so does the same happen here or is that only in QCD?

Comment: You appear to be misusing the [conventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables#Feynman_diagrams) terms. A few diagrams would be worth 1000 words.

Comment: The link shows Feynman diagrams for $s$ channel, $u$ channel, and $t$ channel.  I was just asking which diagrams would you need to sum over when considering tree level $q \overline{q} \rightarrow ZZ$, as it seems to me like you would have to consider all of them?

Comment: If the dashed line represents  a Z  in the first and a quark in the latter two, then, yes, why should you not consider all three? What is special about QCD?

Comment: I hope you are not asking if there are trilinear Z couplings at tree level in the SM… have you considered the Higgs?

Comment: No no, I know there aren't ZZZ couplings in the SM at tree level.   The document I was reading was seeming to suggest that there was something special about QCD, so I was just clarifying the confusion.